# Url in wordpress admin page auto remove the parameter

Tags: wordpress

Please help me with this,

When i login to wp-admin page and select one option like yoat seo plugin
so the normal url is 
`/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard` 
but i dont know why my site it auto remove the `?page=wpseo_dashboard` so my url now is 
`/wp-admin/admin.php`
and this happen to every other plugin.
Can anyone please help me with this :( Thanks so much.

Comment: Which Wordpress version you have?

Comment: Deactivate all your plugins and check with the normal pages!

Comment: i'm trying but still the same, when i get the site back to localhost everything is ok, but when it in host server those things happen...

Comment: The thing which deals with permalink is `.htaccess` Look deeper into that

Comment: can u spot me where is this file ? only 1 i know is in root folder and it's just some default line of wordpress nothing else